# How to replace Ubuntu with Lubuntu OS via USB when internal drive will not unmount?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, ubuntu-20.04

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on my laptop and want to replace it with Lubuntu 22.04 LST. I have a usb stick with the Lubuntu ISO installed using BalenaEtcher. When installing the Lubuntu OS there is no option to wipe the old Ubuntu OS. The reason for the USB stick is that my laptop does not have a CD drive.
[image]

I have tried to manually partition the disk but this still does not work since I am unable to press the NEXT button.
[image]

Running the lsblk command from the Lubuntu OS on the USB stick shows the following file structure:
[image]

I have also tried to unmount the disk via KDE Partition Manager when on the Lubuntu OS but again it fails:
[image]

Any ideas what to do next and how to resolve this issue would be greeat. I would really like to wipe the Ubuntu OS and install Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/1/1.3/installation.html#setting-up-partitions), the installer will not give you the "erase disk" option if you have anything on the target device mounted:

> If you have had a previous linux install and want to put the entire disk or just replace an entire partition you will need to unmount them.

The most likely cause for this is that swaps have been automounted. This is a "feature" of the Ubuntu ecosystem to provide as much memory for the live system as possible. Here, too, the manual provides the solution:

```bash
sudo swapoff -a
```

This will unmount them and any partitions with data mounted can be unmounted through `pcmanfm-qt`.

There is an [upstream bug](https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/860) to provide some other solution to this issue.

Comment: I have run sudo swapoff -a on both the ubuntu terminal and the Lubuntu terminal and tried unmounting partitions using pcmanfm-qt however I am still faced with thesame problem. When installing lubuntu I do not have the option to wipe the old OS.